# Windows Template Studio (WinUI 3 in Desktop) - Customize TitleBar

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, winui-3, windows-template-studio, windows-app-sdk

I am a newbie and i am trying to customize the titlebar in the App. I have used Windows Template Studio to create a NavigationView Project for (winui 3 in Desktop) c#. The App does not create a MainWindow.xaml.

I've gone through the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=wasdk), which i have edited the app.xaml.cs to extendscontentintotitlebar = true. This works by extending the content area and removing the titlebar, but i don't know where i need to use settitlebar, since i don't have a mainwindow.xaml to set the UIelement.

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
    public static Window MainWindow { get; set; } = new Window();

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
        Ioc.Default.ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices());
    }

    private void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnLaunched(args);
        var activationService = Ioc.Default.GetService<IActivationService>();
        await activationService.ActivateAsync(args);

        MainWindow.Title = "AppDisplayName".GetLocalized();
        MainWindow.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;
    }
```

How or Where do i set the UIelement and settitlebar in code-behind for the App?

Hope this all makes sense.

Using:
VS2019
Windows App SDK
Windows Template Studio
Windows 10

Jake

Comment: Benefited to someone who has the other [Title bar customization question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/825308/how-to-set-icon-and-color-for-winui3-titlebar-appl.html), you can have a look at the [WinUI3_CustomCaption](https://github.com/castorix/WinUI3_CustomCaption#winui3_customcaption) example.

Comment: @Jwrite: Just call `MainWindow.SetTitleBar` in your App.xaml.cs  class? Or are you asking on how to create the `UIElement` programmatically?